# How to extend / inherit components?

Tags: angular, typescript, inheritance, angular-directive

I would like to create extensions for some components already deployed in Angular 2, without having to rewrite them almost completely, as the base component could undergo changes and wish these changes were also reflected in its derived components.

I created this simple example to try to explain better my questions:

With the following base component `app/base-panel.component.ts`:

```
import {Component, Input} from 'angular2/core';

@Component({
    selector: 'base-panel',
    template: '<div class="panel" [style.background-color]="color" (click)="onClick($event)">{{content}}</div>',
    styles: [`
    .panel{
    padding: 50px;
  }
  `]
})
export class BasePanelComponent { 

  @Input() content: string;

  color: string = "red";

  onClick(event){
    console.log("Click color: " + this.color);
  }
}
```

Would you like to create another derivative component only alter, for example, a basic component behavior in the case of the example color, `app/my-panel.component.ts`:

```
import {Component} from 'angular2/core';
import {BasePanelComponent} from './base-panel.component'

@Component({
    selector: 'my-panel',
    template: '<div class="panel" [style.background-color]="color" (click)="onClick($event)">{{content}}</div>',
    styles: [`
    .panel{
    padding: 50px;
  }
  `]
})
export class MyPanelComponent extends BasePanelComponent{

  constructor() {
    super();
    this.color = "blue";
  }
}
```

[Complete working example in Plunker](http://plnkr.co/edit/bWa1JmH7NaSaJffLsl0x?p=preview)

> Note: Obviously this example is simple and could be solved otherwise no need to use inheritance, but it is intended only to illustrate the real problem.

As you can see in the implementation of the derivative component `app/my-panel.component.ts`, much of the implementation was repeated, and the single part really inherited was the `class` `BasePanelComponent`, but the `@Component` had to basically be completely repeated, not just the changed portions, as the `selector: 'my-panel'`.

Is there some way to make a literally full inheritance of a component Angular2, inheriting the `class` definition of the markings/annotations, as for example `@Component`?

**Edit 1 - Feature Request**

> Feature request angular2 added to the project on GitHub: [Extend/Inherit angular2 components annotations #7968](https://github.com/angular/angular/issues/7968)

**Edit 2 - Closed Request**

> The request was closed, [for this reason](https://github.com/angular/angular/issues/7968#issuecomment-219865739), that briefly would not know how to merge the decorator will be made. Leaving us with no options. So my opinion is is [quoted in the Issue](https://github.com/angular/angular/issues/7968#issuecomment-222496110).

Comment: Check this answer http://stackoverflow.com/questions/36063627/angular2-and-class-inheritance-support Regards

Comment: Ok NicolasB. But my problem is with the inheritance of the decorator @Component, which is not applied to the inheritance metadata. =/

Comment: people, please avoid using inheritance with angular.
e.g. export class PlannedFilterComponent extends AbstractFilterComponent implements OnInit {
is very bad. There are other ways to share code e.g. services  & smaller components. Inheritance is not the angular way. I'm on an angular project where they used inheritance and there are things that break such as exporting components that inherit from abstract components missing inputs of the abstract class.

Comment: use content projection instead e.g. https://github.com/angular/components/blob/master/src/material/card/card.html
don't use inheritance

Answer (score 46):

**Alternative Solution:**

[This answer of Thierry Templier is an alternative way to get around the problem.](https://stackoverflow.com/a/36837482/2290538)

After some questions with Thierry Templier, I came to the following working example that meets my expectations as an alternative to inheritance limitation mentioned in this question:

1 - Create custom decorator:

```
export function CustomComponent(annotation: any) {
  return function (target: Function) {
    var parentTarget = Object.getPrototypeOf(target.prototype).constructor;
    var parentAnnotations = Reflect.getMetadata('annotations', parentTarget);

    var parentAnnotation = parentAnnotations[0];
    Object.keys(parentAnnotation).forEach(key => {
      if (isPresent(parentAnnotation[key])) {
        // verify is annotation typeof function
        if(typeof annotation[key] === 'function'){
          annotation[key] = annotation[key].call(this, parentAnnotation[key]);
        }else if(
        // force override in annotation base
        !isPresent(annotation[key])
        ){
          annotation[key] = parentAnnotation[key];
        }
      }
    });

    var metadata = new Component(annotation);

    Reflect.defineMetadata('annotations', [ metadata ], target);
  }
}
```

2 - Base Component with @Component decorator:

```
@Component({
  // create seletor base for test override property
  selector: 'master',
  template: `
    <div>Test</div>
  `
})
export class AbstractComponent {

}
```

3 - Sub component with @CustomComponent decorator:

```
@CustomComponent({
  // override property annotation
  //selector: 'sub',
  selector: (parentSelector) => { return parentSelector + 'sub'}
})
export class SubComponent extends AbstractComponent {
  constructor() {
  }
}
```

[Plunkr with complete example.](https://plnkr.co/edit/TPps03QCGQCWbX6oVKXp?p=preview)

Comment: I assume that this won't be compatible with offline template compiler.

Comment: @GünterZöchbauer, I have no knowledge about "offline compiler template" of Angular2. But I think that may not be compatible, and it would be an alternative option. Where the mode "offline template compiler" of Angular2 would be useful? You can show me something to better understand about this? So I can understand the importance of this compatibility for my project.

Comment: Offline template compiler (OTC) is not yet functional even though it is already included in RC.3. OTC will analyze the decorators and generate code during a build step when the deployable is generated. OTC allows to remove Angular2 parser and compiler that process decorators and bindings at runtime, which leads to notable smaller code size and faster application and component initialization. OTC will probably become usable with one of the next updates.

Comment: @GünterZöchbauer, now I understand the importance in maintaining the functionality compatible with OTC. It will be a pre-compilation of angular decorators reducing overhead to initialize components. I would like to have known about the functioning of this process and because the solution of this answer will not be compatible with OTC? How is the pre-compilation of decorators? Having this knowledge we might think of something to keep this functional alternative to OTC. Thank you for the clarification!

Answer (score 25):

Angular 2 version 2.3 was just released, and it includes native component inheritance. It looks like you can inherit and override whatever you want, except for templates and styles. Some references:

- [New features in Angular 2.3](https://medium.com/@gerard.sans/angular-2-new-features-in-angular-2-3-f2e73f16a09e)
- [Component Inheritance in Angular 2](https://scotch.io/tutorials/component-inheritance-in-angular-2)
- [A Plunkr demonstrating component inheritance](https://embed.plnkr.co/hMgaYPVRiXMCiKBdfqHy/)

Comment: One "gotcha" here occurs when you forget to specify a new a "selector" in the child component. You will get a runtime error along the lines of ``More than one component matched on this element`` if you do not.

Comment: @TheAelfinn Yeah: each component has to have a complete spec in the `@Component()` tag. But, you can share the .html or .css by referring to the same file if you want. All in all, it's a **big** plus.

Comment: In your second link https://scotch.io/tutorials/component-inheritance-in-angular-2 , the author claims that components inherit their parent's dependency injected services, my code suggests otherwise. Can you confirm that this is supported?

Answer (score 22):

**update**

Component inheritance is supported since [2.3.0-rc.0](https://github.com/angular/angular/blob/master/CHANGELOG.md#230-rc0-2016-11-30)

**original**

So far, the most convenient for me is to keep template & styles into separate `*html` & `*.css` files and specify those through `templateUrl` and `styleUrls`, so it's easy reusable.

```
@Component {
    selector: 'my-panel',
    templateUrl: 'app/components/panel.html', 
    styleUrls: ['app/components/panel.css']
}
export class MyPanelComponent extends BasePanelComponent
```

Comment: This is exactly what I need.  What would the @Component decorator look like for BasePanelComponent?  Could it reference different html/css files? Could it reference the same html/css files referenced by MyPanelComponent?

Comment: This does not inherit `@Input()` and `@Output()` decorators, does it?

Answer (score 21):

Now that [TypeScript 2.2](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/release-notes/typescript-2-2.html) supports [Mixins through Class expressions](http://justinfagnani.com/2015/12/21/real-mixins-with-javascript-classes/) we have a much better way to express Mixins on Components. Mind you that you can also use Component inheritance since angular 2.3 ([discussion](https://github.com/angular/angular/issues/11606)) or a custom decorator as discussed in other answers here. However, I think Mixins have some properties that make them preferable for reusing behavior across components:

- Mixins compose more flexibly, i.e. you can mix and match Mixins on existing components or combine Mixins to form new Components
- Mixin composition remains easy to understand thanks to its obvious linearization to a class inheritance hierarchy
- You can more easily avoid issues with decorators and annotations that plague component inheritance ([discussion](https://github.com/angular/angular/issues/11606))

I strongly suggest you read the TypeScript 2.2 announcement above to understand how Mixins work. The linked discussions in angular GitHub issues provide additional detail.

You'll need these types:

```
export type Constructor<T> = new (...args: any[]) => T;

export class MixinRoot {
}
```

And then you can declare a Mixin like this `Destroyable` mixin that helps components keep track of subscriptions that need to be disposed in `ngOnDestroy`:

```
export function Destroyable<T extends Constructor<{}>>(Base: T) {
  return class Mixin extends Base implements OnDestroy {
    private readonly subscriptions: Subscription[] = [];

    protected registerSubscription(sub: Subscription) {
      this.subscriptions.push(sub);
    }

    public ngOnDestroy() {
      this.subscriptions.forEach(x => x.unsubscribe());
      this.subscriptions.length = 0; // release memory
    }
  };
}
```

To mixin `Destroyable` into a `Component`, you declare your component like this:

```
export class DashboardComponent extends Destroyable(MixinRoot) 
    implements OnInit, OnDestroy { ... }
```

Note that `MixinRoot` is only necessary when you want to `extend` a Mixin composition. You can easily extend multiple mixins e.g. `A extends B(C(D))`. This is the obvious linearization of mixins I was talking about above, e.g. you're effectively composing an inheritnace hierarchy `A -> B -> C -> D`.

In other cases, e.g. when you want to compose Mixins on an existing class, you can apply the Mixin like so:

```
const MyClassWithMixin = MyMixin(MyClass);
```

However, I found the first way works best for `Components` and `Directives`, as these also need to be decorated with `@Component` or `@Directive` anyway.

Comment: this is awesome! thanks for the suggestion. is MixinRoot simply being used as an empty class placeholder here? just want to make sure my understanding is correct.

Comment: @AlexLockwood yup, empty class placeholder is exactly what I'm using it for. I'd happily avoid using it but for now I haven't found a better way to do it.

Comment: I ended up using `function Destroyable<T extends Constructor<{}>>(Base = class { } as T)`. That way I can create mixins using `extends Destroyable()`.

Comment: This looks very good, however is seems that AoT build (Cli1.3) removes ngOnDestroy from DashBoardComponent as it never gets called. (same goes for ngOnInit)

Comment: thanks for this solution. However after a prod build with ionic or angular-cli, the mixin doesn't work somehow, as if it hasn't been extended.

Comment: I've got an error when doing mixing with a generic type like `export class DashboardComponent extends Destroyable(MixinRoot<SomeType>)`, with the generic Destroyable class `export class Destroyable<T> {}`. The typescript error is `value of type is not callable. Did you mean to include 'new' ?`

Answer (score 12):

As far as I know component inheritance has not been implemented yet in Angular 2 and I'm not sure if they have plans to, however since Angular 2 is using typescript (if you've decided to go that route) you can use class inheritance by doing `class MyClass extends OtherClass { ... }`. For component inheritance I'd suggest getting involved with the Angular 2 project by going to https://github.com/angular/angular/issues and submitting a feature request!

Comment: Got it, I'll try in the next days iterating me angular2 project and verify the request feature is no longer in the project issues in Git and if not I will draw up a request for the resource, since it seems to me a very interesting feature. Any extra arguments idea to make the most interesting request?

Comment: Regarding the typescript of the inheritance resource I'm already using in my initial solution (`export class MyPanelComponent extends BasePanelComponent`), the problem is only in the case of Annotations/Decorators are not inherited.

Comment: Yeah, I really don't know what else you could add. I like the idea of either having a new decorator (something like `@SubComponent()`) that marks a class as a subcomponent or having an extra field on the `@Component` decorator that allows you to reference a parent component to inherit from.

Comment: Feature request angular2 added to the project on GitHub: [Extend/Inherit angular2 components annotations #7968](https://github.com/angular/angular/issues/7968)

Answer (score 12):

if you read through the CDK libraries and the material libraries, they're using inheritance but not so much for components themselves, content projection is king IMO. see this link https://blog.angular-university.io/angular-ng-content/ where it says "the key problem with this design"

I know this doesn't answer your question but **I really think inheriting / extending components should be avoided**. Here's my reasoning:

If the abstract class extended by two or more components contains shared logic:
use a service or even create a new typescript class that can be shared between the two components.

If the abstract class... contains shared variables or onClicketc functions,
Then there will be duplication between the html of the two extending components views. This is bad practice & that shared html needs to be broken into Component(s). These Component(s) (parts) can be shared between the two components.

Am I missing other reasons for having an abstract class for components?

An example I saw recently was components extending AutoUnsubscribe:

```
import { Subscription } from 'rxjs';
import { OnDestroy } from '@angular/core';
export abstract class AutoUnsubscribeComponent implements OnDestroy {
  protected infiniteSubscriptions: Array<Subscription>;

  constructor() {
    this.infiniteSubscriptions = [];
  }

  ngOnDestroy() {
    this.infiniteSubscriptions.forEach((subscription) => {
      subscription.unsubscribe();
    });
  }
}
```

this was bas because throughout a large codebase, `infiniteSubscriptions.push()` was only used 10 times. Also importing & extending `AutoUnsubscribe` actually takes more code than just adding `mySubscription.unsubscribe()` in the `ngOnDestroy()` method of the component itself, which required additional logic anyway.

Comment: Ok, I understand your collocation and I agree that aggregation almost solves all the problems that seems to need inheritance. And it's always interesting to think of components as small parts of the application that can be docked in a variety of ways. But in the case of the question the problem is that I do not have control / access to modifications in the component I want to inherit (it is a third component), then aggregation would become unfeasible, and inheritance would be the ideal solution.

Comment: why can't you just make a new component that encapsulates that third party component? What is your third party component out of interest?

e.g. <my-calendar [stuff]=stuff><third-party-calendar [stuff]=stuff></..></..>

Comment: @robertking repeating yourself is very weak pattern... That's why you will starts to hate your job.. instead of enjoying it.

Comment: As for me it's a good idea to extend components in case you want to have the same Input/Output params for a set of components, so they could behave as one. For example I have several registration steps (credentialsStep, addressStep, selectBenefitsStep). They all should have the same Input options(stepName, actionButtons...) and Outputs(complete, cancel).

Comment: @Sergey_T could you consider one component with ng select and content projection? Also repeating a few inputs doesn't seem like you're really saving on much functionality TBH.

Comment: I do have a couple of components that work almost in a same way: the difference is in fact determined by enum value. In base class component code depending on the enum value sent from inherited component class, variables are initialized with one or another service type instance, etc. I combine two approaches - separation by services, selectors, etc. and using two full-fledged components, not mixing their ng state together. Also - now I need to have additional markup in one of the inherited types, so I can isolate its implementation in one of the inherited component classes..

Answer (score 3):

If anyone is looking for an updated solution, Fernando's answer is pretty much perfect. Except that `ComponentMetadata` has been deprecated. Using `Component` instead worked for me.

The full Custom Decorator `CustomDecorator.ts` file looks like this:

```
import 'zone.js';
import 'reflect-metadata';
import { Component } from '@angular/core';
import { isPresent } from "@angular/platform-browser/src/facade/lang";

export function CustomComponent(annotation: any) {
  return function (target: Function) {
    var parentTarget = Object.getPrototypeOf(target.prototype).constructor;
    var parentAnnotations = Reflect.getMetadata('annotations', parentTarget);

    var parentAnnotation = parentAnnotations[0];
    Object.keys(parentAnnotation).forEach(key => {
      if (isPresent(parentAnnotation[key])) {
        // verify is annotation typeof function
        if(typeof annotation[key] === 'function'){
          annotation[key] = annotation[key].call(this, parentAnnotation[key]);
        }else if(
          // force override in annotation base
          !isPresent(annotation[key])
        ){
          annotation[key] = parentAnnotation[key];
        }
      }
    });

    var metadata = new Component(annotation);

    Reflect.defineMetadata('annotations', [ metadata ], target);
  }
}
```

Then import it in to your new component `sub-component.component.ts` file and use `@CustomComponent` instead of `@Component` like this:

```
import { CustomComponent } from './CustomDecorator';
import { AbstractComponent } from 'path/to/file';

...

@CustomComponent({
  selector: 'subcomponent'
})
export class SubComponent extends AbstractComponent {

  constructor() {
    super();
  }

  // Add new logic here!
}
```

Comment: Are custom decorators not highly discouraged? From many other post/threads this solution has been marked as completely wrong because AOT won't support them?

Answer (score 3):

Components can be extended as same as a typescript class inheritance, just that you have to override the selector with a new name. All Input()  and Output() Properties  from the Parent Component works as normal

**Update**

@Component is a decorator,

Decorators are applied during the declaration of class not on objects.

Basically, decorators add some metadata to the class object and that cannot be accessed via inheritance.

If you want to achieve the Decorator Inheritance I would Suggest writing a custom decorator. Something like below example.

```
export function CustomComponent(annotation: any) {
    return function (target: Function) {
    var parentTarget = Object.getPrototypeOf(target.prototype).constructor;

    var parentAnnotations = Reflect.getMetadata('annotations', parentTarget);
    var parentParamTypes = Reflect.getMetadata('design:paramtypes', parentTarget);
    var parentPropMetadata = Reflect.getMetadata('propMetadata', parentTarget);
    var parentParameters = Reflect.getMetadata('parameters', parentTarget);

    var parentAnnotation = parentAnnotations[0];

    Object.keys(parentAnnotation).forEach(key => {
    if (isPresent(parentAnnotation[key])) {
        if (!isPresent(annotation[key])) {
        annotation[key] = parentAnnotation[key];
        }
    }
    });
    // Same for the other metadata
    var metadata = new ComponentMetadata(annotation);

    Reflect.defineMetadata('annotations', [ metadata ], target);
    };
};
```

Refer: 
https://medium.com/@ttemplier/angular2-decorators-and-class-inheritance-905921dbd1b7

Comment: Could you exemplify (using the example of the question) how would that work? You could use [stackblitz](https://stackblitz.com/fork/angular) to develop the example and share the link.

Comment: @Component is a decorator,

Decorators are applied during the declaration of class not on objects.

Comment: You are right. Decorators dosn't make any difference. It is required only if the base component is used as a component somewhere else

Answer (score 3):

You can inherit @Input, @Output, @ViewChild, etc. Look at the sample:

```
@Component({
    template: ''
})
export class BaseComponent {
    @Input() someInput: any = 'something';

    @Output() someOutput: EventEmitter<void> = new EventEmitter<void>();

}

@Component({
    selector: 'app-derived',
    template: '<div (click)="someOutput.emit()">{{someInput}}</div>',
    providers: [
        { provide: BaseComponent, useExisting: DerivedComponent }
    ]
})
export class DerivedComponent {

}
```

Answer (score 2):

Just use inheritance, extend parent class in child class and declare constructor with parent class parameter and this parameter use in `super()`.

1. Parent class:

```
@Component({
  selector: 'teams-players-box',
  templateUrl: '/maxweb/app/app/teams-players-box.component.html'
})
export class TeamsPlayersBoxComponent {
  public _userProfile: UserProfile;
  public _user_img: any;
  public _box_class: string = "about-team teams-blockbox";
  public fullname: string;
  public _index: any;
  public _isView: string;
  indexnumber: number;

  constructor(
    public _userProfilesSvc: UserProfiles,
    public _router: Router,
  ){}
```

2. Child class:

```
@Component({  
  selector: '[teams-players-eligibility]',  
  templateUrl: '/maxweb/app/app/teams-players-eligibility.component.html'  
})  
export class TeamsPlayersEligibilityComponent extends TeamsPlayersBoxComponent {  
  constructor (public _userProfilesSvc: UserProfiles,
    public _router: Router) {  
      super(_userProfilesSvc,_router);  
    }  
  }
```