# How to get the parent class at runtime

Tags: typescript

Is it possible to get the parent class of a TypeScript class at runtime? I mean, for example, within a decorator:

```
export function CustomDecorator(data: any) {
  return function (target: Function) {
    var parentTarget = ?
  }
}
```

My custom decorator is applied this way:

```
export class AbstractClass {
  (...)
}

@CustomDecorator({
  (...)
})
export class SubClass extends AbstractClass {
  (...)
}
```

Within the decorator, I would like to have an instance to `AbstractClass`.

Thanks very much for your help!

Comment: I don't get it. Just checking for instanceof does not do the job?

Comment: In fact, I have some metadata associated on the parent class using reflect-metadata. I would like to have access to these hints ;-)

Comment: You could pass it in: `@CustomDecorator(eval("_super"))` -- Don't do this ;)

Answer (score 17, accepted):

You can use the [Object.getPrototypeOf](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/getPrototypeOf) function.

Something like:

```
class A {
    constructor() {}
}

class B extends A {
    constructor() {
        super();
    }
}

class C extends B {
    constructor() {
        super();
    }
}

var a = new A();
var b = new B();
var c = new C();

Object.getPrototypeOf(a); // returns Object {}
Object.getPrototypeOf(b); // returns A {}
Object.getPrototypeOf(c); // returns B {}
```

---

#### Edit

[After the code](http://www.typescriptlang.org/play/#src=function%20CustomDecorator(data%3A%20any)%20%7B%0D%0A%20%20return%20function%20(target%3A%20Function)%20%7B%0D%0A%09console.log(target)%3B%0D%0A%20%20%09console.log(Object.getPrototypeOf(target))%3B%0D%0A%20%20%7D%0D%0A%7D%0D%0A%0D%0Aclass%20AbstractClass%20%7B%0D%0A%20%20name%3A%20string%3B%0D%0A%7D%0D%0A%0D%0A%40CustomDecorator(%7B%7D)%0D%0Aclass%20SubClass%20extends%20AbstractClass%20%7B%0D%0A%0D%0A%7D) @DavidSherret added (in a comment), here's what you want (I think):

```
export function CustomDecorator(data: any) {
  return function (target: Function) {
    var parentTarget = target.prototype;
    ...
  }
}
```

Or as @DavidSherret noted:

```
function CustomDecorator(data: any) {
  return function (target: Function) {
    console.log(Object.getPrototypeOf(new (target as any)));
  }
}
```

---

#### 2nd Edit

Ok, so here's what I hope to be you goal:

```
function CustomDecorator(data: any) {
    return function (target: Function) {
        var parentTarget = Object.getPrototypeOf(target.prototype).constructor;
        console.log(parentTarget === AbstractClass); // true :)
    }
}
```

Comment: I don't think this works inside the decorator function

Comment: Why not? Should work the same regardless of the scope it's in.. Can you supply the code? maybe a link to Playground?

Comment: [see here](http://www.typescriptlang.org/play/#src=function%20CustomDecorator(data%3A%20any)%20%7B%0D%0A%20%20return%20function%20(target%3A%20Function)%20%7B%0D%0A%09console.log(target)%3B%0D%0A%20%20%09console.log(Object.getPrototypeOf(target))%3B%0D%0A%20%20%7D%0D%0A%7D%0D%0A%0D%0Aclass%20AbstractClass%20%7B%0D%0A%20%20name%3A%20string%3B%0D%0A%7D%0D%0A%0D%0A%40CustomDecorator(%7B%7D)%0D%0Aclass%20SubClass%20extends%20AbstractClass%20%7B%0D%0A%0D%0A%7D) -- oh wait, i just realized this solution is dealing with instances instead of the function directly

Comment: Yeah, just need to [create an instance first](http://www.typescriptlang.org/play/#src=function%20CustomDecorator(data%3A%20any)%20%7B%0D%0A%20%20return%20function%20(target%3A%20Function)%20%7B%0D%0A%20%20%09console.log(Object.getPrototypeOf(new%20(target%20as%20any)))%3B%0D%0A%20%20%7D%0D%0A%7D%0D%0A%0D%0Aclass%20AbstractClass%20%7B%0D%0A%20%20name%3A%20string%3B%0D%0A%7D%0D%0A%0D%0A%40CustomDecorator(%7B%7D)%0D%0Aclass%20SubClass%20extends%20AbstractClass%20%7B%0D%0A%0D%0A%7D)

Comment: @DavidSherret. Oh, right, cuz you get the constructor. in that case should be easy.  revised answer.

Comment: oh wow, yeah doing `target.prototype` is definitely the better way. Seems pretty obvious now that you pointed it out haha. I think it would be good to update the answer to just have `target.prototype` to cut to the chase... no need to list the `Object.getPrototypeof(new ...)` solution because that can have issues when the constructor expects parameters

Comment: @DavidSherret It's another option, and maybe the OP will find it more suited for his needs (or future readers) so I tend towards keeping it, but if you'd like I'll remove it from the answer.

Comment: Thanks guys for your help! Unfortunately the protytotype isn't exactly the class :-(  The prototype corresponds to the constructor function associated with the class. In my use case, the parent class is decorated and metadata are set on it using reflect-metadata. But these metadata aren't present on this constructor function. See this plunkr: https://plnkr.co/edit/A2Gcs2MGULZ7Bn1xBEFN?p=preview.

Comment: @ThierryTemplier Can you maybe write up a short code example in Playground so I may see exactly what's up?  That plnkr is too much to deal with.

Comment: @NitzanTomer perhaps this one: http://www.typescriptlang.org/play/#src=function%20CustomDecorator(data%3A%20any)%20%7B%0D%0A%20%20return%20function%20(target%3A%20Function)%20%7B%0D%0A%09console.log(target)%3B%0D%0A%20%20%09console.log(Object.getPrototypeOf(target))%3B%0D%0A%20%20%7D%0D%0A%7D%0D%0A%0D%0Aclass%20AbstractClass%20%7B%0D%0A%20%20name%3A%20string%3B%0D%0A%7D%0D%0A%0D%0A%40CustomDecorator(%7B%7D)%0D%0Aclass%20SubClass%20extends%20AbstractClass%20%7B%0D%0A%0D%0A%7D. ;-)

Comment: The problem is that `target.prototype === AbstractClass` returns false

Comment: @ThierryTemplier check out my 2nd edit of the answer

Comment: Umm, `Object.getPrototypeOf(target.prototype).constructor;` is actually just a complicated way of saying `Object.getPrototypeOf(target);`. Is there any point to not just getting the base constructor directly like that?

Answer (score 0):

For me following construct worked for getting base type constructor from a type constructor:

```js
class Validator {
    constructor(private readonly ctr: ConstructorFunction<T>) {
        this.id = ctr.name;
        //...
        let protoRef = ctr['__proto__'] as Function;
        this._inheritFrom = protoRef && protoRef !== Object ? protoRef.name : null;
        this._inheritsFromValidator = null;
        //...
    }
}
```

Yeah this is not sound as fancy as smth as `ctr.getBaseClassConstructor()` a-la

```
type BaseType<T> = [some-magic]<T>
function getBasicType<T>():BaseType<T>;
```

but that trick with `__proto__` work.