# How to get successive base classes in typescript

Tags: typescript

I'd like to walk up the super type chain all the way to Object, so given:

```
abstract class Foo {}

abstract class Bar extends Foo {}

abstract class Baz extends Bar {}

class Yolo extends Baz {}

let yolo = new Baz()
```

How can I get all the extended classes Baz, Bar, Foo, and Object with an instance of yolo?

I saw [How to get the parent class at runtime](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36867005/how-to-get-the-parent-class-at-runtime) and I don't see how that would help me, I can only go up one level.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `getPrototypeOf` successively to walk up the super chain:

```
var ctor = yolo.constructor;
while(ctor !== null){
    console.log(ctor);
    ctor = Object.getPrototypeOf(ctor);    
}
```

Will output:

```
function Yolo() { … }
function Baz() { … }
function Bar() { … }
function Foo() { … }
function () { … }
Object { … }
```