# Access a object's class's static methods in Typescript?

Tags: javascript, typescript, class, static, static-methods

```
class Base {
  static f(){console.log('Base')}
}

class A extends Base {
  static f(){console.log('A')}
}

class B extends Base {
  static f(){console.log('B')}
}

let obj: A|B = new A()

obj.<what to put here>.f()
```

I don't know the exact class for obj, I need to print A or just call `f()` for correct class of obj.

I don't need just the class name, that is for example.
I am doing more complex things.

`prototype, typeof, constructor` all seem to be syntax errors.

Comment: Are you guaranteed that `obj` is either an instance of `A` or `B`?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to get the parent class at runtime](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36867005/how-to-get-the-parent-class-at-runtime)

Comment: `Object.getPrototypeOf(obj).constructor.f();` works for me

Comment: `obj.constructor.f()` is not a syntax error for sure. Did you mean you're getting a type error? If so, which one?

Comment: Typescript thinks `obj.constructor` is a `Function` hence shows an error, but works correctly when cast as `<any>`. `Object.getPrototypeOf(obj).constructor.f()` works.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Both [Object.getPrototypeOf()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/getPrototypeOf) (replacement to the now deprecated [`Object.prototype.__proto__`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/proto)) or [`Object.prototype.constructor`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/constructor) should work:

```
Object.getPrototypeOf(obj).constructor.f();

obj.constructor.f();
```

Actually:

```
Object.getPrototypeOf(obj).constructor === obj.constructor; // true
```

Here you can see the compiled source in action:

```js
class Base {
  static f() { console.log('Base'); }
}

class A extends Base {
  static f() { console.log('A'); }
}

class B extends Base {
  static f() { console.log('B'); }
}

const objBase = new Base();
const objA = new A();
const objB = new B();

Object.getPrototypeOf(objBase).constructor.f();
objBase.constructor.f();

Object.getPrototypeOf(objA).constructor.f();
objA.constructor.f();

Object.getPrototypeOf(objB).constructor.f();
objB.constructor.f();

console.log(Object.getPrototypeOf(objB).constructor === objB.constructor);
console.log(Object.getPrototypeOf(objB) === B.prototype);
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper {
  max-height: none !important;
}
```

Note static properties exist in classes but not in instances.

Therefore, if you want to go from `obj` to its prototype, you should call `Object.getPrototypeOf(obj)`, not `obj.prototype`, which is a completely different thing.

The `.prototype` property only exists in functions and, when instantiating a new object using `new` and a call to that constructor function (`new A()`), will become the newly created object's prototype (the deprecated `.__proto__`).

In your example:

```
obj.prototype;                // undefined
A;                            // class A { static f() { ... } }
A.protoype;                   // { constructor: class A { ... } }
A.protoype.constructor;       // class A { static f() { ... } }
A.protoype.constructor === A; // true
obj.constructor;              // class A { static f() { ... } }
obj.constructor === A;        // true

Object.getPrototypeOf(obj) === A.prototype; // true
```

Comment: Thanks, these solutions worked. Typescript thinks `obj.constructor` is a `Function` hence shows an error, but works correctly when cast as `<any>`.