# Angular2 use imported libs from base class

Tags: typescript, angular

"angular2": "2.0.0-beta.17",

I'd like to be able to `import { Http, Response } from 'angular2/http';` in my `Base` and use `http` in the child classes.

Is there a way to achieve this ?

P.S. I'm not looking for a "clean" solution, hacks, workarounds and things like this are welcome

The base class:

```
import { Http, Response } from 'angular2/http';

export class ServiceBase {
  constructor (private http: Http) {}

}
```

And a child class:

```
import { ApiServiceBase } from '../../api-service-base';
import { Injectable }     from 'angular2/core';
// import { Http, Response } from 'angular2/http';
import { AuthUser }       from './auth_user';
import { Observable }     from 'rxjs/Observable';
import { Headers, RequestOptions } from 'angular2/http';
import 'rxjs/add/operator/toPromise';

@Injectable()
export class LoginService extends ApiServiceBase {
  constructor () {
    super();
  }
  private url = 'http://localhost:8080/api/signin';

  login (user: AuthUser): Promise<AuthUser> {
    let body = JSON.stringify(user);
    let headers = new Headers({ 'Content-Type': 'application/json' });
    let options = new RequestOptions({ headers: headers });
    return this.http.post(this.url, body, options)
               .toPromise()
               .then(this.extractData)
               .catch(this.handleError);
  }

  private extractData(res: Response) {
    console.log(res);
    if (res.status < 200 || res.status >= 300) {
      throw new Error('Bad response status: ' + res.status);
    }
    let body = res.json();
    return body.data || { };
  }

  private handleError (error: any) {
  }
}
```

Comment: Why don't you want the import in the child class?

Comment: But I thought, you don't care about a "clean" solution? This is going to be way less "hacky" then the alternative, no?

Comment: Adding all of this extra complexity just for the sake of avoiding a one line `import` seems unnecessary. In fact, you already have an import from `angular2/http` in your child class for `Headers` and `RequestOptions` - why not just add `Http` and `Response` to that?

Comment: it's not just one line, it's one line for every child service. and this will come in handy when I'll want to add something to all my `child services`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Using a parent class to define dependency injection of sub classes isn't supported in Angular2.

The only thing you can do here if you want to use the `http` instance in the parent class:

```
@Injectable()
export class LoginService extends ApiServiceBase {
  constructor (http:Http) {
    super(http);
  }

  (...)
}
```

**Edit**

A workaround would consist of defining a custom decorator to set the metadata for dependency injection:

```
export function CustomInjectable(annotation: any) {
  return function (target: Function) {
    var parentTarget = Object.getPrototypeOf(target.prototype).constructor;
    var parentAnnotations = Reflect.getMetadata('design:paramtypes', parentTarget);

    Reflect.defineMetadata('design:paramtypes', parentAnnotations, target);
  }
}
```

It will leverage the metadata from the parent constructor instead of its own ones. You can use it on the child class:

```
@Injectable()
export class BaseService {
  constructor(protected http:Http) {
  }
}

@CustomInjectable()
export class TestService extends BaseService {
  constructor() {
    super(arguments);
  }

  test() {
    console.log('http = '+this.http);
  }
}
```

See this plunkr: https://plnkr.co/edit/DIMyUB6rCE5d78dPlPZB?p=preview.

Comment: that's why I'm looking for a hack to achieve this

Comment: I'm looking for a way to avoid the `import` in the child class

Comment: would it be possible to use grunt or something like this for this task. Like a preprocessor of some sort, that will import everything for me, since the `ts` has to be transformed to ES5, it should be possible to add an additional step to the transpilation process that would handle the imports

Comment: The problem is that it's the `Injectable` decorator that actually configures the injection basing the constructor of the sub class...

Comment: An approach would be to implement a custom decorator that looks into the parent class instead of the current one to configure DI. In this case, you wouldn't need to define a constructor in the child class. I implemented something like that but for components. See this question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/36837421/extending-component-decorator-with-base-class-decorator/36837482#36837482. Perhaps something like that could be done... Let me make a try ;-)

Comment: I updated my answer and provided a working plunkr for this approach. Feel free to tell me if it suits your needs...

Comment: wow, you know your stuff for sure. can you suggest me some books/resources to read ? I never really understood how javascript works, the books that I tried explained things very shallow.. thanks a lot

Comment: Hi, I'm getting this error with your example: [ts] Supplied parameters do not match any signature of call target.
function CustomInjectable(annotation: any): (target: Function) => void

Comment: from your plunker console:
`Array [ Http() ]  main.ts!transpiled:24:13
http = [object Arguments]`
if I amend super call with spread operator `super(...arguments);` then it outs:
`Array [ Http() ]  main.ts!transpiled:24:13
http = undefined`
how do you think this should work?