# How to define Angular class hierarchy with service dependencies

Tags: angular, service, dependency-injection, model, class-hierarchy

My head is going around in circles on this one.

I want to create classes to represent data returned from the back end in Angular (not AngularJS).

I have two top level classes `Variation` and `Reallocation`. Both are types of base class `Adjustment`. Therefore both `Variation` and `Reallocation` **extend** `Adjustment`. Most of the class definition is in the `Adjustment` class with only small, but important, differences between the two derived classes.

It seems to make sense to use the `Adjustment` class to handle most of the communication with the back-end. That is, say I want to get a `Variation`. I should be able to pass an id to a `getAdjustment` method of `Variation` and have it return an instance of `Variation` populated with data from the server.

So far that all makes logical sense to me and I CAN get it to work.

The problem is that somewhere along the line I have to use a service to get data from the backend. I happen to be using AngularFirestore to get data.

So, in my `Adjustment` class I have to include a constructor something along the following lines:

```
constructor(
     public afs: AngularFirestore,
     ....){}
```

The problem then is when I come to use super() in my derived class. I have to inject AngularFirestore into the derived class as well. That is, I have to have something like:

```
export class Variation extends Adjustment {
....
constructor(
    afs: AngularFirestore,
    .... ) {}
super (afs,
        ....)
```

The `Variation` class doesn't really need to know anything about AngularFirestore but I have to inject it in this class to enable it to be injected in the `Adjustment` class.

There must be a way to avoid this but I just can't figure it out.

Comment: I don't think there's a way around this, but if there is, I'd love to see it :)

Comment: I've had to do it this way as well. Maybe it could be done differently if property injection were available, but right now you have go through the constructor so I don't see another way.

Comment: Thanks for your comments. At least I'm not missing something really obvious.

Answer (score 0):

## Edit

I've replaced my previous answer with the following:

I did some more research on injectors and found this answer: https://stackoverflow.com/a/37482645/5348742.

We know Angular maintains an application-wide injector. We can access this injector by creating an property of type `Injector` at whatever module level we need. If we have registered the service in `root` we can get the injector in `app.module`.

In this way, we don't have to get the injector for the service in the constructor.

We get a reference to the service in `app.module`, export it and and then use it anywhere we need it.

Check the link above for further details on getting a reference to the service.

As far as using it elsewhere in the app it goes something like this.

In `app.module`

```
...

export let myService: MyService;

export class AppModule {

constructor(private router: Router,
        private injector: Injector){
        appInjector = this.injector;
        myService = appInjector.get(MyService)
  }
}
```

And then in the component or class where you want to use it:

```
import { myService } from 'app.module'

...

export class MyClass {

constructor(...){...}

  getSomething(){
    const something = myService.doSomething()
  }
}
```

In this way we can use a service without having to declare it in the constructor.