# How to instantiate an angular 2 service without using the constructor?

Tags: angular, typescript

I'm trying to use my ApiService class (handling api requests) in another class, but can't get it to work.  
The issue is the ApiService constructor needs HttpClient, that means I can't just use something like: http = new ApiService(new HttpClient(), globals)

ApiService:

```
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
import { HttpClient, HttpRequest } from '@angular/common/http';
import { Globals } from './globals';

@Injectable({
  providedIn: 'root'
})
export class ApiService {
  constructor(private http: HttpClient, private globals: Globals) {}

  get(url : string, params: {}){
    return this.http.get(this.globals.api_url.concat(url), {params: params});
  }

  ...
}
```

Class calling ApiService:

```
export class UploadAdapter {
    http: ApiService;
    constructor() {}

    upload() {
           //Here I get an error saying can't get post of undefined 
       http.post('api_url'.concat('/medias/upload'), {}, {})
         .subscribe((data) => {
            //do stuff here.
         });
    }



}
```

Comment: To instantiate a class without its constructor sounds like nonsense.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37482460/getting-instance-of-service-without-constructor-injection

Answer (score 1):

You are not injecting the service in your component

Your `UploadAdapter` constructor should be like this

`constructor(private http: ApiService) {}`

Also you need to use

`this.http.post`

Instead of

`http.post`

Comment: Hi Asim, 
The thing is UploadAdapter isn't a component just another service itself to handle communication with the api.
I can't inject the ApiService in the constructor of UploadAdapter, otherwise when instantiating it I need use something in the line of: new UploadAdapter(new ApiService(new HttpClient, new Globals ()))