# What to pass the `super` class constructor of `MatDiolog` when keep multiple class

Tags: angular, typescript, ecmascript-6

Base class: since my ts file handling multiple features I am splitting them.

```
   constructor(
           
        ) {
            super(MatDialog);
        }
```

error: `Argument of type 'typeof MatDialog' is not assignable to parameter of type 'MatDialog'.`

super class:

```
export class AddClicnicComponent {
    popTableSchema;
    tableSchema;
    @ViewChild('popupTemp', { static: true })
    popupTemp: TemplateRef<HTMLAllCollection>;

    constructor(public dialog: MatDialog) {
        console.log('i am called by super');
    }
    handleAddClinic() {
        this.popTableSchema = { ...this.tableSchema };
        this.openDialog(this.popupTemp);
    }
    openDialog(templateRef: TemplateRef<HTMLAllCollection>) {
        const dialogRef = this.dialog.open(templateRef);
        dialogRef.afterClosed().subscribe((result) => {
            console.log(`Dialog result: ${result}`);
        });
    }
}
```

What are the exact params I need to send with super? Can't I avoid the params?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you should first add the `MatDialog` dependency to the constructor and then pass that instance to the super something like

```
constructor(public dialog: MatDialog) {
            super(dialog); //instance(i.e dialog) is passed here instead of type MatDialog
        }
```

Comment: It works. but need to construct in 2 place? can't it avoidable?

Comment: @3gwebtrain if you are inheriting and want to pass dependency to the constructor than you will have to do it this way or you can get the dependency directly see following question https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37482460/getting-instance-of-service-without-constructor-injection

Answer (score 0):

You are sending the class definition to the parent class but you need to send the class istance.

Comment: How to send, can you help me? I tried to send like this `new MatDiolog()` but it needs 7 argument in it

Comment: Share the code of the class that extends AddClijicComponent and i will help you

Comment: error `Expected 7 arguments, but got 0.ts(2554)`