# Is it possible to decorate a decorator in Typescript?

Tags: typescript, angular, decorator

Building a component library and there is a fair amount of boilerplate in the @Component decorator. For instance style and template urls are always the same relative path. Wondering if it's possible to use a decorator to DRY it up.

I suppose I could write a decorator that duplicates those parts of the @Component functionality, but I was hoping to leverage what's already there.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you can certainly extend Component functionality and abstract some functionality,
Below is the solution based upon [Extending component decorator with base class decorator](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36837421/extending-component-decorator-with-base-class-decorator/)

**component-metadata.ts**

```
    import "reflect-metadata";
    import { ComponentMetadata } from "@angular/core";

    export function MyComponent(annotation: any): any {
      return function (target: Function) {
         let parentTarget = Object.getPrototypeOf(target.prototype).constructor;
         let parentAnnotations = Reflect.getMetadata("annotations", parentTarget);

         let parentAnnotation = parentAnnotations[0];
         Object.keys(parentAnnotation).forEach(key => {
           if (isPresent(parentAnnotation[key])) {
              annotation[key] = parentAnnotation[key];
           }
        });

        let fileName: string = annotation.moduleId.substring(0, annotation.moduleId.lastIndexOf("."));
        annotation["templateUrl"] = fileName + ".html";
        annotation["styleUrls"] = [fileName + ".css"];        
        let metadata: ComponentMetadata = new ComponentMetadata(annotation);

        Reflect.defineMetadata("annotations", [metadata], target);
     }
   }
```

Assumptions are that html and css are in the same folder as component definition and have same name, you may update based upon your need.
For e.g.

**html** :  some.component.html

**css** : some.component.css

**some.component.ts**

```
   @MyComponent({
     selector: "some-component",
     moduleId: module.id 
   })
   export class SomeComponent{
      // Class implementation
   }
```

Comment: Great! Thank you for the detailed example.