# Angular2 inherit decorators in derived class

Tags: inheritance, angular

I have the `BaseComponent` with `template` set. I want to use the same template HTML in a component extending base one. I know class inheritance in Angular2 is only for classes and not for decorators. So it looks like I need a new decorator which will find parent class and all its decorators and apply to current class. Some properties of decorators should be possible to change (like `selector` for `@Component`).

Comment: See also https://github.com/angular/angular/issues/7968

Answer (score 1):

You could create your own component that create and register component metadata leveraging the one from its parent class.

Something like that:

```
export function CustomComponent(annotation: any) {
  return function (target: Function) {
    var parentTarget = Object.getPrototypeOf(target.prototype).constructor;
    var parentAnnotations = Reflect.getMetadata('annotations', parentTarget);

    var parentAnnotation = parentAnnotations[0];
    Object.keys(parentAnnotation).forEach(key => {
      if (isPresent(parentAnnotation[key])) {
        annotation[key] = parentAnnotation[key];
      }
    });
    var metadata = new ComponentMetadata(annotation);

    Reflect.defineMetadata('annotations', [ metadata ], target);
  }
}
```

You can use it this way:

```
@Component({
  template: `
    (...)
  `
})
export class ParentComponent {
}

@CustomComponent({
  selector: 'test'
})
export class ChildComponent extends ParentComponent {
}
```

See this question for more details:

- [Extending component decorator with base class decorator](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36837421/extending-component-decorator-with-base-class-decorator/)

Comment: I use Angular beta rc1. `ComponentMetadata`, `Reflect.getMetadata()`, `isPresent()` and `Reflect.defineMetadata()` are unknown. What should I import?