# Custom component with ion-slide

Tags: ionic2

I am trying ionic2 beta9 and am trying to create a custom component with ion-slide, but I am getting an error.

### **Parent Component**

```
<ion-content class="home" padding>    
  <ion-slides loop="true">
    <slide-item *ngFor="let image of [1,2,3,4,5]" [imgIdx]="image"></slide-item>
  </ion-slides>
</ion-content>
```

### **slide-item Custom Component**

```
<ion-slide>
        <div class="bcontent">
            <div class="bimg">
                <img data-src="images/slide{{imgIdx}}.jpeg">
            </div>
            <p class="info">My text</p>
        </div>
</ion-slide>
```

### **slide-item.ts**

```
@Component({
  selector: 'slide-item',
  templateUrl: 'build/components/slide-item/slide-item.html',
  directives: [Slides, Slide]
})
export class SlideItem {

  @Input()
  imgIdx: number;

  constructor() {
    console.log("SlideItem::constructor...imgIdx="+this.imgIdx);
  }
}
```

### **I am getting the following error:**

zone.js:461

```
Unhandled Promise rejection: Template parse errors:
No provider for Slides ("
  for more info on Angular 2 Components.
-->
[ERROR ->]<ion-slide>
        <div class="bcontent">
            <div class="bimg">
"): SlideItem@6:0
```

; Zone: angular ; Task: Promise.then ; Value:

```
BaseException {message: "Template parse errors:↵No provider for Slides ("↵ …↵            <div class="bimg">↵"): 
SlideItem@6:0", stack: "Error: Template parse errors:↵No provider for Slid…ndroid_asset/www/build/js/app.bundle.js:30622:41)"}message: 
"Template parse errors:↵No provider for Slides ("↵  for more info on Angular 2 Components.↵-->↵[ERROR ->]<ion-slide>↵        <div class="bcontent">↵            <div class="bimg">↵"): SlideItem@6:0"

stack: "Error: Template parse errors:↵No provider for Slides ("↵  for more info on Angular 2 Components.↵-->↵[ERROR ->]<ion-slide>↵        <div class="bcontent">↵            <div class="bimg">↵"): SlideItem@6:0↵    at new BaseException (file:///android_asset/www/build/js/app.bundle.js:1760:23)↵    at TemplateParser.parse (file:///android_asset/www/build/js/app.bundle.js:16401:19)↵    at file:///android_asset/www/build/js/app.bundle.js:14643:64↵    at ZoneDelegate.invoke (file:///android_asset/www/build/js/zone.js:323:29)↵    at Object.onInvoke (file:///android_asset/www/build/js/app.bundle.js:30631:41)↵    at ZoneDelegate.invoke (file:///android_asset/www/build/js/zone.js:322:35)↵    at Zone.run (file:///android_asset/www/build/js/zone.js:216:44)↵    at file:///android_asset/www/build/js/zone.js:571:58↵    at ZoneDelegate.invokeTask (file:///android_asset/www/build/js/zone.js:356:38)↵    at Object.onInvokeTask (file:///android_asset/www/build/js/app.bundle.js:30622:41)"__proto__: ErrorconsoleError @ zone.js:461_loop_1 @ zone.js:490drainMicroTaskQueue @ zone.js:494ZoneTask.invoke @ zone.js:426
```

Comment: Did you get anywhere with this? I added `providers: [Slides]` in the `Slide.decorators` in **ionic-angular/components/slides/slides.js** and the error goes away. The slides are not rendered correctly, though, so I'm still working on it.

Answer (score 0):

**Why it doesn't work**

I don't think it is possible with the current design of the Slide and Slides components. An `ion-slide` must be a child of an `ion-slides` element and it must be able to find its parent Slides *within the same template*.

Here's the source:

```
@Component({
  selector: 'ion-slide',
  template: '<div class="slide-zoom"><ng-content></ng-content></div>',
  changeDetection: ChangeDetectionStrategy.OnPush,
  encapsulation: ViewEncapsulation.None,
})
export class Slide {

  ele: HTMLElement;

  @Input() zoom: any;

  constructor(
    elementRef: ElementRef,
    @Host() public slides: Slides
  ) {
    this.ele = elementRef.nativeElement;
    this.ele.classList.add('swiper-slide');

    slides.rapidUpdate();
  }

  ngOnDestroy() {
    this.slides.rapidUpdate();
  }
}
```

You can see that the parent `Slides` is required so that a `Slide` can trigger the `Slides` to update when one is dynamically added or destroyed. It is restricted to the current template with the `@Host` decorator.

You get a template error when you try to use `ion-slide` in your custom template because there is no `Slides` object within the template to be passed to the `Slide`.

**One Partial-Solution**

I played around with this and you can get it to work like this:

1. Remove the reference `slides` to the parent `Slides` object, sacrificing the ability to automatically update the `Slides` when you dynamically add/remove slides
2. Add the "slide-zoom" class to your custom slide.

The modified source for slides.ts:

```
@Component({
  selector: 'ion-slide',
  template: '<div class="slide-zoom"><ng-content></ng-content></div>',
  changeDetection: ChangeDetectionStrategy.OnPush,
  encapsulation: ViewEncapsulation.None,
})
export class Slide {

  ele: HTMLElement;

  @Input() zoom: any;

  constructor(
    elementRef: ElementRef
  ) {
    this.ele = elementRef.nativeElement;
    this.ele.classList.add('swiper-slide');
  }
}
```

And your slide item:

```
@Component({
  selector: 'slide-item',
  templateUrl: 'slide-item.html',
})
export class SlideItem {

  @Input()
  imgIdx: number;

  constructor(elementRef: ElementRef) {
    console.log("SlideItem::constructor...imgIdx="+this.imgIdx);
    elementRef.nativeElement.classList.add('swiper-slide');
  }
}
```

I say that this is a *partial* solution because you have to modify the ionic source and because now you have to manually call update the `Slides` update when you add/remove slides.

I did make some progress further modifying the ionic source to maintain the automatic update on add/remove slides including custom slide containers such as yours. But it just wasn't looking worth it compared to the option(s) below.

**Partial Solution 2**

The code for a `Slide` is really quite simple. You're best bet is probably just to define your own component directly (rather than wrapping `ion-slide`):

```
@Component({
  selector: 'slide-item',
  templateURL: 'slite-item.html',
  changeDetection: ChangeDetectionStrategy.OnPush,
  encapsulation: ViewEncapsulation.None,
})
export class SlideItem {

  ele: HTMLElement;

  @Input() zoom: any;
  @Input() imgIdx: number;

  constructor(
    elementRef: ElementRef
  ) {
    this.ele = elementRef.nativeElement;
    this.ele.classList.add('swiper-slide');

    console.log("SlideItem::constructor...imgIdx="+this.imgIdx)
  }
}
```

and template

```
<div class="slide-zoom bcontent">
  <div class="bimg">
    <img data-src="images/slide{{imgIdx}}.jpeg">
  </div>
  <p class="info">My text</p>
</div>
```

I'm calling this one a partial solution also because you have to maintain some extra source that mirrors Ionic. If the ionic slides implementation changes, you may have to update your custom slide.

**Improved Solution**

[Here is a SO answer about extending a component](https://stackoverflow.com/a/36837482/484488). I haven't gotten this to work because as of now it isn't up to date with Angular (`ComponentMetaData` no longer exists), but I think it is a nicer approach. You will use this decorator to import and extend the `Slide` component.

```
export function CustomComponent(annotation: any) {
  return function (target: Function) {
    var parentTarget = Object.getPrototypeOf(target.prototype).constructor;
    var parentAnnotations = Reflect.getMetadata('annotations', parentTarget);

    var parentAnnotation = parentAnnotations[0];
    Object.keys(parentAnnotation).forEach(key => {
      if (isPresent(parentAnnotation[key])) {
        annotation[key] = parentAnnotation[key];
      }
    });
    var metadata = new ComponentMetadata(annotation);

    Reflect.defineMetadata('annotations', [ metadata ], target);
  }
}
```

Your template will be the same as the previous solution, but the class is simplified to something like the following.

```
import { Slide } from 'ionic-angular';

@CustomComponent({
  selector: 'slide-item',
  templateURL: 'slite-item.html'
})
export class SlideItem extends Slide {
  @Input() imgIdx: number;
}
```