# Angular2 @HostListener won't work in derived component

Tags: angular, typescript, angular2-template

I have an application with Angular2-based client side.
I have a base class:

```
abstract class BaseClass {
    @HostListener('window:beforeunload') beforeUnloadHandler() {
        console.log('bla');
    }
}
```

and two very similar to each other derived classes:

```
@Component({
    selector:  'derived-one',
    templateUrl:  './templates/app/+derived-one/derived-one.component.html'
})
export class DerivedOne extends BaseClass {
}

@Component({
    selector:  'derived-two',
    templateUrl:  './templates/app/+derived-two/derived-two.component.html'
})
export class DerivedTwo extends BaseClass {
}
```

The problem is that, for example, in `DerivedOne` `beforeUnloadHandler` works fine while in `DerivedTwo` it doesn’t receive a call at all.

I know it’s hard to find the reason why it happens just looking on the information above, but maybe someone might have a suspicion what could cause such strange behavior.

A few more notes:

If I use the following :

```
abstract class BaseClass
    constructor(){
        window.onbeforeunload = function(){
            console.log('bla');
        }
    }
}
```

everything works fine, but I still would like to find an Angular2-based solution;

If I write

```
abstract class BaseClass {
    beforeUnloadHandler() {
        console.log('bla');
    }
}
```

and in `derived-two.component.html`

```
<div (window.beforeunload)="beforeUnloadHandler()"></div>
```

everything works fine too, but it looks like an ugly hack;

Again, if I write

```
abstract class BaseClass {
    beforeUnloadHandler() {
        console.log('bla');
    }
}
```

and

```
@Component({
    selector:  'derived-two',
    host: {'window:beforeunload': 'beforeUnloadHandler' }
    templateUrl:  './templates/app/+derived-two/derived-two.component.html'
})
export class DerivedTwo extends BaseClass {
}
```

it won’t work.

Finally, if I use `@HostListener` in `DerivedTwo` and in `DerivedOne`, it works, but I would like to avoid using duplicate code.

Hopefully, the information above would be enough to work with (at least to have some guesses).

Comment: Please, clarify what are the conditions for the class to not behave correctly. Is DerivedTwo the one that doesn't work? Are the components used simultaneously in view? Does it depend on the order in which they are imported or the order in which they appear in view?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

**Update 2.3.0**

You can now take advantage of object inheritance for components.

More details you can see in this commit https://github.com/angular/angular/commit/f5c8e0989d85bc064f689fc3595207dfb29413f4

**Old Version**

1) If you have a class:

```
abstract class BaseClass {
  @HostListener('window:beforeunload') beforeUnloadHander() {
    console.log('bla');
  }
}
```

then it will work

**[Plunker Example](https://plnkr.co/edit/DB5A7IYFRWhi9s7w0Jzj?p=preview)** (put whitespace somewhere in editor and watch console)

**but be careful** since **Angular2 doesn't support the full inheritance** - [Issue with binding and @ViewChild](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38153962/issue-with-binding-and-viewchild)

> But it still unclear why the solution with @HostListener didn't work
>   in first place

Specifically if you have a property decorator on your derived component it won't work. For example let's say we have the following code:

```
abstract class BaseClass {
  @HostListener('window:beforeunload') beforeUnloadHander() {
    console.log(`bla-bla from${this.constructor.name}`);
  } 
} 

@Component({
    selector:  'derived-one',
    template:  '<h2>derived-one</h2>'
})
export class DerivedOne extends BaseClass {
   @Input() test;
}
```

**[Plunker](https://plnkr.co/edit/fLxhnni5TOzeDgyLOWK1?p=preview)**

It will be transformed to javascript like:

```
var core_1 = require('@angular/core');
var BaseClass = (function () {
    function BaseClass() {
    }
    BaseClass.prototype.beforeUnloadHander = function () {
        console.log("bla-bla from" + this.constructor.name);
    };
    __decorate([
        core_1.HostListener('window:beforeunload'), 
        __metadata('design:type', Function), 
        __metadata('design:paramtypes', []), 
        __metadata('design:returntype', void 0)
    ], BaseClass.prototype, "beforeUnloadHander", null);
    return BaseClass;
}());
var DerivedOne = (function (_super) {
    __extends(DerivedOne, _super);
    function DerivedOne() {
        _super.apply(this, arguments);
    }
    __decorate([
        core_1.Input(), 
        __metadata('design:type', Object)
    ], DerivedOne.prototype, "test", void 0);
    DerivedOne = __decorate([
        core_1.Component({
            selector: 'derived-one',
            template: '<h2>derived-one</h2>'
        }), 
        __metadata('design:paramtypes', [])
    ], DerivedOne);
    return DerivedOne;
}(BaseClass));
```

We are interested in the following lines:

```
 __decorate([
    core_1.HostListener('window:beforeunload'), 
      __metadata('design:type', Function), 
      __metadata('design:paramtypes', []), 
      __metadata('design:returntype', void 0)
 ], BaseClass.prototype, "beforeUnloadHander", null);

 ... 
 __decorate([
   core_1.Input(), 
   __metadata('design:type', Object)
 ], DerivedOne.prototype, "test", void 0);
```

`HostListener` and `Input` are property decorators (`propMetadata` key). This way will define two metadata entries - on `BaseClass` and on `DerivedOne`
[image]
[image]

Finally when angular2 will extract metadata from `DerivedOne` class it will only use its own metadata:

[image]

To get all the metadata you can write custom decorator like:

```
function InheritPropMetadata() {
  return (target: Function) => {
    const targetProps = Reflect.getMetadata('propMetadata', target);

    const parentTarget = Object.getPrototypeOf(target.prototype).constructor;
    const parentProps = Reflect.getMetadata('propMetadata', parentTarget);

    const mergedProps = Object.assign(targetProps, parentProps);

    Reflect.defineMetadata('propMetadata', mergedProps, target);
  };
};

@InheritPropMetadata()
export class DerivedOne extends BaseClass {
```

Here's a working **[demo](https://plnkr.co/edit/gChdnTFzKpvUUwaL3Zmv?p=preview)**

2) If you done as follows:

```
abstract class BaseClass
  constructor(){
    window.onbeforeunload = function(){
      console.log('bla');
    };
  }
}
```

then it will be invoked only one time because you're overriding `window.onbeforeunload` handler everytime
You should use the following instead:

```
abstract class BaseClass {
 constructor(){
    window.addEventListener('beforeunload', () =>{
      console.log(`bla-bla from${this.constructor.name}`);
    })
  }
}
```

**[Plunker Example](https://plnkr.co/edit/uP5byjPw45jMUd40kEPt?p=preview)**

3) Finally if you have base class as shown below:

```
abstract class BaseClass {
  beforeUnloadHander() {
     console.log(`bla-bla from${this.constructor.name}`);
  }
}
```

then you have to use the correct syntax (**you're missing
brackets**) in decorator property:

```
host: {'(window:beforeunload)': 'beforeUnloadHander()' }
```

**[Plunker Example](https://plnkr.co/edit/Otln8VTmcqOAqYUGwhvw?p=preview)**

Hope it helps you!

Comment: Thank you, kind sir, it really did help! I chose the third option, by the way (I still can't believe I made a syntax mistake). But it still unclear why the solution with `@HostListener` didn't work in first place.

Comment: Wow, THAT was really helpful! I wish I could like your answer twice :D