# Input properties in inherited angular 2 components

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript, inheritance

I'm trying to implement components in angular 2 by inheriting some base class which has some Input properties (I've used [this example](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36063627/angular2-and-class-inheritance-support) as a guide for implementing inheritance for angular 2 components).

**Simplified Example**

```
export class ComponentBase {
  @Input() text: string = "base";
}

@Component({
  selector: "derived-comp",
  templateUrl: "derived-comp.template.html",
  providers: [
    { provide: ComponentBase, useExisting: forwardRef(() => DerivedComponent) }
  ]
})
export class DerivedComponent extends ComponentBase {
  @Input() dummy: number;
}
```

It all works as expected, until I add a new Input property in derived component (dummy, in the provided sample). When I do that, all of the Input properties defined in base class become invisible in runtime (although everything is ok at compile-time), and there's an error in browser console saying that those inputs don't exist:

> Can't bind to 'text' since it isn't a known property of
>   'derived-comp.'

Has anyone had a similar problem with component inheritance in angular 2? Does anyone have a suggestion on how to overcome it (other than copy-paste of the code)?

Comment: Check this question http://stackoverflow.com/questions/38153962/issue-with-binding-and-viewchild

Comment: Thanks yurzui! I've seen the post from Thierry Templier, but it seems that I haven't read it carefully at the time. It's a shame that in order to use inheritance for ang2 components you have to use reflection and some "tricks"...

Answer (score 0):

Maybe in old Angular versions this was a p.i.a., but now it's very easy. See [this post](https://coryrylan.com/blog/angular-component-inheritance-and-template-swapping)