# Angular2 Dart - Component inheritance

Tags: inheritance, angular, dart

How Angular2 component inheritance (e.g. inputs reuse) can be implemented with Dart?
Found number of issues on github, but [seems that it will not be supported by default in Angular2](https://github.com/angular/angular/issues/7968#issuecomment-219865739). Also found [workaround](https://stackoverflow.com/a/36837482/5521491), but looks like it's applicable on TypeScript only.

Comment: This is possible with Angular 4: https://medium.com/dartlang/annotate-once-angulardart-825479b1e78f

Answer (score 1):

That's not supported in general and also not for Dart.

Comment: I understood, but maybe is there some workaround (like `@Component` extension) to reuse specific subset of `@Component` parameters?

Comment: I'm pretty sure there isn't. I wouldn't build on the mentioned TS workaround as well because it probably won't work with several features (like Universal or offline template compiler) and is prone to break at any time without notification anyway.

Comment: Ok about `ComponentMetadata` fields, but is it some known bug that when component class extends one that implements some lifecycle hook, it doesn't works?

Comment: There are a few issues like https://github.com/angular/angular/issues/6781, https://github.com/angular/angular/issues/5415. Maybe others, don't remember.

Comment: It's sad.. Thanks a lot!