# How to import/use Reflect in typescript

Tags: javascript, node.js, typescript

I'm trying to use the code in [this SO answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/36837482/484488). It uses Reflect. Here's a copy:

```
export function CustomComponent(annotation: any) {
  return function (target: Function) {
    var parentTarget = Object.getPrototypeOf(target.prototype).constructor;
    var parentAnnotations = Reflect.getMetadata('annotations', parentTarget);

    var parentAnnotation = parentAnnotations[0];
    Object.keys(parentAnnotation).forEach(key => {
      if (isPresent(parentAnnotation[key])) {
        annotation[key] = parentAnnotation[key];
      }
    });
    var metadata = new ComponentMetadata(annotation);

    Reflect.defineMetadata('annotations', [ metadata ], target);
  }
}
```

First, I got these two errors:

```
Property 'getMetadata' does not exist on type 'typeof Reflect'.
Property 'defineMetadata' does not exist on type 'typeof Reflect'.
```

Then I ran `npm install reflect-metadata`, but I don't know how to use it.

```
import { Reflect } from reflect-metadata;

Module '".../node_modules/reflect-metadata/index"' has no exported
member 'Reflect'.
```

Or

```
import { Reflect } from 'reflect-metadata/Reflect';

Cannot find name 'Record'. 
Type '{}' is not assignable to type 'V'.
File '.../node_modules/reflect-metadata/Reflect.ts' is not a module.
```

Or

```
import "reflect-metadata"

rollup: Treating 'fs' as external dependency 
bundle update failed: Error transforming .../node_modules/typescript/lib/typescript.js
with 'commonjs' plugin: The keyword 'package' is reserved (57066:28) in
.../node_modules/typescript/lib/typescript.js
```

Or

```
var reflect = require("reflect-metadata");

Cannot find name 'require'.
```

Or

```
declare var require: any;
var reflect = require("reflect-metadata");
var Reflect = reflect.Reflect;

    rollup: Treating 'fs' as external dependency 
bundle update failed: Error transforming .../node_modules/typescript/lib/typescript.js
with 'commonjs' plugin: The keyword 'package' is reserved (57066:28) in
.../node_modules/typescript/lib/typescript.js
```

Surely I'm just missing something silly, even a typo. What can I do to use this code?

Answer (score 28, accepted):

**you have to import the type declarations** together with the (js) library

```
npm install reflect-metadata -D
```

inside your .ts file:

```
 import "reflect-metadata";
```

Comment: Thanks, the bundle update failed error is something else.

Comment: import "reflect-metadata"; causes eslint to complain about "Imported module should be assigned". Its not a good codding style.

Comment: What about `isPresent()`?

Comment: function isPresent(obj: any): boolean {
    return obj !== undefined && obj !== null;
  }

Answer (score 12):

As of today, `@types/reflect-metadata` is deprecated since `reflect-metadata` includes already its own typings.

So, to use them you just need to import the library (Uses the global scope). That's it.

1. Install it:
   `npm install reflect-metadata --save`
2. Import it:
   `import 'reflect-metadata';`

Answer (score 3):

Typescript uses a Module loading paradigm that's a bit different than that of JavaScript.

Say you have a module `Modulus` that defines three classes `A`, `B` and `C`.

```
import { A } from "Modulus"
```

will import the class (or function) `A` from the module `Modulus` and make it available in your current module. If Typescript finds no export named `A` in `Modulus` and error will be thrown.

```
// Equivalent to the following in JavaScript:
// var ModuleNameOfYourChoice = require("Modulus")

import * as ModuleNameOfYourChoice from "Modulus"
```

will import all the exports declared within `Modulus` and make them available to the current module under the name `ModuleNameOfYourChoice`.

For your code, you need all the exports defined in `reflect-metadata` module and thus need to import it as

```
import * as Reflect from "reflect-metadata"
```

All the best!

Typescript documentation: http://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/modules.html#import

Answer (score -1):

I found another solution if you can use es7+. So in your `tsconfig.json` file you need to change only one line. Change assigment of `"target"` to at least **es2017**. And that's all now you can use `Reflect` out of the box. I think it is very good solution because you do not have to care about additional dependencies

**Example `tsconfig.json`**

```
{
  "compilerOptions": {
    "experimentalDecorators": true,
    "outDir": "../dist",
    "module": "umd",
    "target": "es2017",
    "sourceMap": true,
    "noImplicitAny": true,
    "strictNullChecks": true,
    "removeComments": false,
    "moduleResolution": "node"
  },
  "exclude": [
    "node_modules",
    "bower_components",
    "dist"
  ]
}
```

Comment: @Jackie hmm it is weird for me that works. Can you provide any example ?

Comment: sure I am playing around with it now here https://github.com/jrgleason/rollup-ng-typescript-demo/tree/MJS_CALLING_TS

Comment: @Jackie i am getting 404 if I try to open this link