# Replacement for ComponentMetadata in angular

Tags: angular

I'm trying to use the code in [this SO answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/36837482/484488), which uses `ComponentMetadata`. It looks like it used to be in angular/core, but I guess it is no longer available?

Here is the code. What can I do to get the `metadata` used in the last line?

```
function ExtendComponent(annotation: any) {
  return function (target: Function) {
    var parentTarget = Object.getPrototypeOf(target.prototype).constructor;
    var parentAnnotations = Reflect.getMetadata('annotations', parentTarget);

    var parentAnnotation = parentAnnotations[0];
    Object.keys(parentAnnotation).forEach(key => {
      if (isPresent(parentAnnotation[key])) {
        // verify is annotation typeof function
        if(typeof annotation[key] === 'function'){
          annotation[key] = annotation[key].call(this, parentAnnotation[key]);
        }else if(
        // force override in annotation base
        !isPresent(annotation[key])
        ){
          annotation[key] = parentAnnotation[key];
        }
      }
    });

    var metadata = new ComponentMetadata(annotation);
    Reflect.defineMetadata('annotations', [ metadata ], target);
  }
}
```

I'm really shooting in the dark here, but I found this test in the angular source, which uses `MetadataCollector`.

```
import { MetadataCollector } from '@angular/tsc-wrapped';
...
const collector = new MetadataCollector({quotedNames: true});
...
const metadata = collector.getMetadata(source);
const componentMetadata = metadata.metadata['MyComponent'];
```

Would this even be a replacement? I tried to check it out, but at `new MetadataCollector({quotedNames: true})` I get

```
Supplied parameters do not match any signature of call target.
```

And even if I try `new MetadataCollector()`, I get this rollup warning and bundle update failed error:

```
 rollup: Treating 'fs' as external dependency
 bundle update failed: Error transforming .../node_modules/typescript/lib/typescript.js 
 with 'commonjs' plugin: The keyword 'package' is reserved (57066:28) in .../node_modules/typescript/lib/typescript.js
```

Answer (score 5):

Since ComponentMetadata is deprecated, We need to use

```
var  metadata = new Component(annotation);
```