# Additional resource reference in the angular component

Tags: angular

For example, we have a file with localized strings

```
{
  "title": "Example title",
  "description": "Some text"
}
```

Let's assume we also have a component with some custom decorator `@I18n()`

```
@Component({ ... })
@I18n('./my-translations.json')
export class MyAngularComponent {

}
```

And template

```
<h2>{{ i18n.title }}</h2>
<p>{{ i18n.description }}</p>
```

Is it possible to include one more external resource (besides `templateUrl` and `styleUrls`) into the component?

Comment: Sounds like you want to extend the @Component decorator -> https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36837421/extending-component-decorator-with-base-class-decorator

Comment: Extending the @Component decorator is also an option. The problem is to asynchronously load external resource before Angular creates the component.

Answer (score 2):

You could extend `Component` decorator however i would not do that, since it may have undesired effects on compiler and depends on `Component` changes between angular versions. I would rather allow multiple arguments/variable arguments/array parameter in `I18n` decoroator or allow multiple `I18n` decorators, it means that `I18n` decorator should check for class modifications done by previous decorators and append its data accordingly.

Comment: Yes, I can add multiple parameters to the `I18n` decorator like
`@I18n('./en.json', './fr.json', './es.json')`. But how to make it load the correspondent json file.

Comment: Without control over library that provides I18n decorator you can not change its behaviour.

Comment: `I18n` is not a part of a library. It's might be my own code supposed to load a file and assign it's data to the field `i18n` of the component in order to use it in the template (see example above)

Comment: I just don't see a way to load a file located next to the component source code

Comment: Webpack allows importing json files as objects (depending on version), then you can pass imported objects to decorator, which can merge objects into class field.

Comment: Sounds promising :). Could you provide a link or an example? Don't really understand how to do that import.

Comment: Since webpack >= v2.0.0, importing of JSON files will work by default.  i.e. `import { Translations } from '../translations/translations.json';`

Comment: If I have a few JSON files for different languages then I have to import all of them and pass into the decorator. It's not really what I want.

Comment: You can use webpacks replace plugin and adjust locale at build time

Comment: Can I use it with Angular CLI?

Comment: See https://medium.com/dailyjs/angular-cli-6-under-the-hood-builders-demystified-f0690ebcf01