# Create Component Factory in Angular

Tags: angular, typescript

In an Angular project, I tried to create a component from a factory:

```js
export const ComponentFactory = (partial: any) =>
  Component({ ...partial });
```

```js
@ComponentFactory ({
  selector: 'app-a-component',
  templateUrl: './a-component.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./a-component.component.scss'],
})
export class AComponent {}
```

I received this error message:

> The class 'Component' is listed in the declarations of the NgModule 'Module', but is not a directive, a component, or a pipe. Either remove it from the NgModule's declarations, or add an appropriate Angular decorator.

While debugging I reduced to the simplest case:

```js
const X = Component
@X({
  selector: 'app-a-component',
  templateUrl: './a-component.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./a-component.component.scss'],
})
export class AComponent {}
```

And I received the very same error message. Since `X` is equal to `Component` it should pass all runtime checks, so a supposition is that Angular makes some parsing making it impossible to create custom `Component` decorators, but from some [SO question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36837421/extending-component-decorator-with-base-class-decorator) seems to be possible.

Why manually setting metadata works, while using a decorator identical to Angular's built-in `Component` doesn't? Am I missing something?
Since I only need to operate on `partial` object, I would like to use `Component` in my factory so that it's less likely it needs to be changes in newer Angular versions.

Comment: You have to reload your project, sometimes after I created some component, I need to run ng serve again

Comment: It's not the case. I realoaded the project and the problem is still here

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The Ivy engine only allows `@Component({...})`. The decorator data needs to be specified as an object literal (see https://angular.io/errors/NG1001) because it lifts there declarations and places them in another location in the class output. The same goes for `@NgModule`, `@Pipe`, `@Component`, `@Directive`, and `@Injectable`.

Ivy probably only does a quick static check looking for `@Component` on a class declaration, so using `X` is not detected.