# How to implement a lib in angular2

Tags: angular, typescript

I have a function and it's being used in different components.
To use it across few components, i am pasting the same code in each component. 
I want to create a lib, in which i will write this method and then import it across the components. Please suggest a way how to approach.

```
@Component({
  // Some metadata 
})
export class ComA  {
   dataValid(val: any): string {
       // some login
    }
}   



@Component({
  // Some metadata 
})
export class ComB  {
   dataValid(val: any): string {
       // some login
    }
}
```

Here i am using dataValid() function repeatedly.

I want some thig like

```
@Component({
  // Some metadata 
})
export class ComA extends GenericLib {

}   



@Component({
  // Some metadata 
})
export class ComB extends GenericLib {

}
```

And use dataValid() function in GenericLib class

Comment: What's the problem? What have you tried? Components are also in libraries. Put your code in a `*.ts` file. prefix declarations (classes, variables, functions) with `export` (like you did with the components) and then import and use it wherever you please.

Comment: I am using follwing code :-                                                        @Component({})
export class GenericLib implements OnInit {   
dataValid(val: any): string {
       // some login
    }  }                and getting following error : ---     No template specified for component GenericLib

Comment: Sounds about right. `@Component({})` should be `@Component({selector: 'xxx', template: '<div>my template here</div>})`

Comment: That's fine but since I am creating a lib for reusing my methods there is no need for creating a template in the selector.

Comment: Quite confused what you think a "lib" is. What are you planning to do with it?

Comment: My aim is to place the reusable method in a class and extend it in others class. So that if I want to modify the method I do not have to go to each class, just modify it at one place . Did you get it ?

Comment: The problem is then related to components and inheritance, but not to library. See for example https://scotch.io/tutorials/component-inheritance-in-angular-2, http://stackoverflow.com/questions/36475626/how-to-extend-inherit-angular2-component, https://medium.com/@amcdnl/inheritance-in-angular2-components-206a167fc259#.5moevmjsr

Comment: Thanks URL helped a lot !!