# Repeated methods in components in angular2

Tags: angular, typescript, angular2-components

So I have same methods being used in each of my components, this, of course is not good practice. Is it possible to create a new class with these methods and just call them in each of my components? Is there an angular2 approach?

Please advice.

Thanks

Comment: You can simply use a service to this. Got resources to implement services in angular? 'google'

Comment: Can it be approached by creating a class of these methods and create instance of these? @SaiyaffFarouk

Comment: Depending on angular2 version, you may be able to use inheritance http://stackoverflow.com/a/41346665/5660649

Comment: create a super class, and extends this class to use these methods

Comment: Hmm, I see, that its more suitable to go ahead with OO principle @BoChen