# angular aot doesn't execute lifecycle hooks from mixins classes

Tags: angular, typescript, inheritance, mixins

I'm using the following mixing from [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36475626/how-to-extend-inherit-angular2-component)
which gives my components access to a set of reusable methods, inlcuding calling upon the lifecycle hooks.

However with AOT build, it seems that OnInit and OnDestroy wont' get triggered. Is there a solution to enforce it?

```
export function Destroyable<T extends Constructor<{}>>(Base: T) {
  return class Mixin extends Base implements OnDestroy {
    private readonly subscriptions: Subscription[] = [];

    protected registerSubscription(sub: Subscription) {
      this.subscriptions.push(sub);
    }

    public ngOnDestroy() {
      this.subscriptions.forEach(x => x.unsubscribe());
      this.subscriptions.length = 0; // release memory
    }
  };
}
```

in any component

```
export class CMP extends destroyable(){
     constructor(){ super() }
}
```

Comment: Angular AOT can't evaluate functions.

Comment: so i need to use a class instead of return it with a function

Comment: I'm pretty sure yes. Except when you use the dynamic platform to compile components at runtime. I'd expect this to cause an error though.

Comment: i just tried it with classes and it works with aot. thanks for the hint for dynamic platform for future references