# Angular 6 @ContentChildren doesn't query extended component

Tags: angular, components, angular6

i've got a question about the ContentChildren decorator.

I want to create a controller user interface for the desktop. 
I created some components to handle the controller input (so a example for, lets say the start page could be this):

- ControllerInputWrapperComponent (extends ControllerContainerComponent)

  - ControllerContainerComponent

    - Panel (extends ControllerContainerComponent)
    - Panel (extends ControllerContainerComponent)
  - ControllerContainerComponent

    - Panel (extends ControllerContainerComponent)
    - Panel (extends ControllerContainerComponent)
    - Panel (extends ControllerContainerComponent)
    - DifPanel (extends ControllerContainerComponent)

The ControllerContainerComponent template looks like this:

`<template #host></template>
<ng-content></ng-content>`

(The template is a optional choice to generate panels by a json template)

Now I want the ControllerContainerComponent to query its children that are instance of ControllerContainerComponent. If i use ControllerContainerComponent as the selector in the @ComponentChildren decorator it returns a empty list after the content has been initialized.

After that I tried to query the exact class (in this case the PanelComponent) and then got some results, but they wouldn't include components like DifPanelComponent

My question is:

Is this a issue with angular or did I do something wrong?

EDIT:

I found a question on stackoverflow that is kind of similiar, but does not quite give the answer I was looking for and is not about the current version of angular: [Angular 2 - Using @ContentChildren for filtering a component's content](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38126774/angular-2-using-contentchildren-for-filtering-a-components-content?rq=1)

2nd EDIT:

Here is a stackblitz that demonstrates my problem: https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-vfmnd3

Comment: Please consider creating a Stackblitz.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You may need to `provide` it.
`providers:[{provide: ControllerContainerComponent, useExisting:Panel}]`
Then you'd be able to query it.

Comment: Thank you, it was a great help, but the final solution was found here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36063627/angular2-and-class-inheritance-support