# angular2 @ContentChildren with a base class post RC4

Tags: angular

With Angular2 RC1 to RC4 if you wanted to get child components which derived from a base class you could do something like:

```
@Component({    
...
providers: [ provide(BaseComponent,{ useExisting: forwardRef( () => Panel) )}
```

And your content children property would look like:

```
@ContentChildren(BaseComponent) allBaseComponents;
```

I think it was RC5 where 'provide' was depreciated. With 2.0.0 'provide' has been removed.  How do we now get child components which have a common base class?

Here is more detail on the RC4 'provide' [solution](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36063627/angular2-and-class-inheritance-support?rq=1) from stackoverflow

Comment: You use `providers: [{ provide: BaseComponent, useExistng:   }]`, but I don't think that is necessary to be able to use `ContentChildren`

Comment: I updated http://stackoverflow.com/questions/36063627/angular2-and-class-inheritance-support?rq=1

Answer (score 0):

`provide(X, { Y })` was replaced with a simple object literal. So instead of calling `provide` explicitly, just write it like the following:

```
providers: [
    { provide: BaseComponent, useExisting: forwardRef(() => Panel) }
]
```

Then, you can still use `@ContentChildren` with the base component type, just like you are used to.

Comment: Thank you!  I was close to this, just had the syntax a bit wrong.  For the other answer, I had tried doing

Answer (score -1):

What you do is:

```
@ContentChildren(BaseComponent) allBaseComponents: QueryList<BaseComponent>;
```

You do not have to provide anything. Notice that `allBaseComponents` will be available from certain life cycle hook and don't forget to import `ContentChildren` and `QueryList` from `@angular/core`.

Comment: You should not do it in a lifecycle hook at all, it should be at the top of your class.

Comment: Yes, what I ment was that `allBaseComponents` will be available in certain life hook. In onNgInit it will be null.