# Why does Python start at index -1 (as opposed to 0) when indexing a list from the end?

Tags: python, list

```py
list = ["a", "b", "c", "d"]
print(list[3]) # Number 3 is "d"

print(list[-4]) # Number -4 is "a"
```

Comment: Don't use `list` as a variable name, it's the name of a standard class.

Comment: It isn't starting at 1, it's starting at -1. ?!?

Comment: [mod arithmetic](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Modular_arithmetic) should really be mentioned on this page somewhere...

Comment: Should that say `as opposed to -0`? Since it starts at 0 when indexing from the start, it is trivial that it can't be 0 from the end, so I think -0 is what is meant.

Comment: Did you *try* accessing index 0?

Comment: There is a really simple way to understand why '-1' is a reference to the last character of the string. The end of the string points to the right of the string (past the last character) so a '-1' moves one character left and now points to the start of the last character. This is fully symmetric with '0' referring to the start of the string where '0' points to the left of the first character so using an index of 0 gets the next character which is the first character of the string.

Answer (score 185, accepted):

To explain it in another way, because `-0` is equal to `0`, if backward starts from `0`, it is ambiguous to the interpreter.

---

If you are confused about `-`,  and looking for another way to index backwards more understandably, you can try `~`, it is a mirror of forward:

```
arr = ["a", "b", "c", "d"]
print(arr[~0])   # d
print(arr[~1])   # c
```

The typical usages for `~` are like "swap mirror node" or "find median in a sort list":

```
"""swap mirror node"""
def reverse(arr: List[int]) -> None:
    for i in range(len(arr) // 2):
        arr[i], arr[~i] = arr[~i], arr[i]

"""find median in a sort list"""
def median(arr: List[float]) -> float:
    mid = len(arr) // 2
    return (arr[mid] + arr[~mid]) / 2

"""deal with mirror pairs"""
# verify the number is strobogrammatic, strobogrammatic number looks the same when rotated 180 degrees
def is_strobogrammatic(num: str) -> bool:
    return all(num[i] + num[~i] in '696 00 11 88' for i in range(len(num) // 2 + 1))
```

`~` actually is a math trick of inverse code and complement code, and it is more easy to understand in some situations.

---

Discussion about whether should use python tricks like `~`:

In my opinion, if it is a code maintained by yourself, you can use any trick to avoid potential bug or achieve goal easier, because of maybe a high readability and usability. But in team work, **avoid using 'too clever' code**, may bring troubles to your co-workers.

For example, here is one concise code from [Stefan Pochmann](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1672429/stefan-pochmann) to solve [this problem](https://leetcode.com/problems/strobogrammatic-number-ii/). I learned a lot from his code. But some are just for fun, too hackish to use.

```
# a strobogrammatic number is a number that looks the same when rotated 180 degrees (looked at upside down)
# find all strobogrammatic numbers that are of length = n
def findStrobogrammatic(self, n):
    nums = n % 2 * list('018') or ['']
    while n > 1:
        n -= 2
        # n < 2 is so genius here
        nums = [a + num + b for a, b in '00 11 88 69 96'.split()[n < 2:] for num in nums]
    return nums
```

I have summarized [python tricks](https://github.com/recnac-itna/python_tricks) like this, in case you are interested.

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/191880/discussion-on-answer-by-recnac-why-does-python-start-at-index-1-when-iterating-a).

Comment: Could you provide description of the problem that Stefan's code solves? I don't want to register at leetcode only to access that information.It's also good when the answers contain all relevant details.

Comment: Problem Description: A strobogrammatic number is a number that looks the same when rotated 180 degrees (looked at upside down). Find all strobogrammatic numbers that are of length = n. And the key points of Stefan's code: First line, if nums is odd, the middle will in '018', we will add pair to leftmost and rightmost in while loop, but we should consider number can not start with '0', so `n<2` is used here. just 5 line solve a complex problem. @Konrad

Comment: Donor use this method. You still need to understand the underlying use of negative indexing for indexing from the end. This is just further obfuscation.

Answer (score 175):

```
list[-1]
```

Is short hand for:

```
list[len(list)-1]
```

The `len(list)` part is implicit. That's why the `-1` is the last element. That goes for any negative index - the subtraction from `len(list)` is always implicit

Comment: In my opinion this answer is better than the accepted one.

Comment: Be aware that list[-n] and list[len(list)-n] are only equivilent for values of n between 1 and len(list). This becomes especially important when slicing rather than indexing.

Answer (score 28):

This is the mnemonic method I use. It is just an approach of what is happening, but it works.

---

Don't think of those as indexes. Think of them as offsets on a circular list.

Let's use the list x = [a,b,c,d,e,f,g,h] as an example. Think about x[2] and x[-2]:

[image]

You start at offset zero. If you move two steps forward, you're going from a to b (0 to 1), and them from b to c (1 to 2).

If you move two steps backward, you're going from a to h (0 to -1), and then from h to g (-1 to -2)

Comment: "Think about a[2] and a[-2]" is `a` the list, or an element of the list?

Comment: "a" is an hypothetical list which contains the values a-h! I'll clarify!

Comment: Note the similarity with modular arithmetic.

Answer (score 24):

Because `-0` in Python is `0`. 
With `0` you get first element of list and
 with `-1` you get the last element of the list

```
list = ["a", "b", "c", "d"]
print(list[0]) # "a"
print(list[-1]) # d
```

> You can also think it as shorthand for `list[len(list) - x]` where x is the element position from the back.
>   *This is valid only if `0 < -(-x) < len(list)`*

```
print(list[-1]) # d
print(list[len(list) - 1]) # d
print(list[-5]) # list index out of range
print(list[len(list) - 5]) # a
```

Comment: I think `-0` is `0` pretty much everywhere.

Comment: @KorayTugay Except in floating point.

Comment: I guess that is not `0` anymore. @Barmar

Comment: @KorayTugay It is. The binary representation is even all 0s. Floating point also just has another 0, where the sign bit is 1.

Comment: @Barmar There were architectures where 0 and -0 were distinct values even for integral values (sign and magnitude).  I don't believe any processors now on the market use this representation though.

Answer (score 14):

This idiom can be justified using modular arithmetic. We can think of indices as referring to a cell in a list *obtained by walking forward `i` elements*. `-1` referring to the last element of the list is a natural generalization of this, since we arrive at the last element in the list if we walk backwards one step from the start of the list.

For any list `xs` and index `i` *positive or negative*, the expression

```
xs[i]
```

will either have the same value as the expression below or produce an `IndexError`:

```
xs[i % len(xs)]
```

The index of the last element is `-1 + len(xs)` which is congruent to `-1` mod `len(xs)`. For example, in an array of length 12, the canonical index of the last element is 11. 11 is congruent to -1 mod 12.

In Python, though, arrays are more often used as *linear* data structures than *circular* ones, so indices larger than `-1 + len(xs)` or smaller than `-len(xs)` are out of bounds since there's seldom a need for them and the effects would be really counterintuitive if the size of the array ever changed.

Answer (score 8):

Another explanation:

Your finger points to the first element. The index decides how many places you shift your finger to the right. If the number is negative, you shift your finger to the left.

Of course, you can't step to the left from the first element, so the first step to the left wraps around to the last element.

Answer (score 6):

You could intuitively understand it this way

```
steps= ["a", "b", "c", "d"]
```

Suppose you start from `a` to `d`, a is your staring point where you stand (or your home), so mark it as 0(because you did not move yet),

Move one step to b, second step to c and arrive at third d.

Then how about you return from d to a (or return from your office to your home). Your home is `0` because your family live there, so your office cannot be a `0`.It's your last stop.

So when you return back to home. d is the last first stop to where you start off for  home, c is the last second ....

Comment: `d is the last first stop to start, c is the last second ` This is kind of difficult to understand, could you dissect that sentence a bit?

Comment: `last` here is ending or final, not recent @RaimundKrämer