# When to extend and provide an abstract class in Angular?

Tags: angular, typescript

```
@Component({
  selector: 'my-component',
  template: `<ng-content></ng-content>`,
  providers: [
    { provide: AbstractClass, useExisting: forwardRef(() => TargetComponent) }
  ]
})
export class TargetComponent extends AbstractClass implements OnInit {

}
```

What is the purpose of both prividing and extending a class in Angular?

I dont understand why do we need to provide when we extend an abstract class

Comment: Are you sure you didn't mean to write `forwardRef(() => TargetComponent)` (which would allow TargetComponent to be used when AbstractClass is requested)? Related answer: https://stackoverflow.com/a/37041446/1127114

Comment: Maybe it's just me, but I prefer composition over inheritance when using Angular DI classes.

Answer (score 0):

The connection between the two lies in the fact that `TargetComponent` both provides `AbstractClass` (or its subclass) for dependency injection within Angular's DI system and extends `AbstractClass` to inherit its behaviour and structure. This combination allows `TargetComponent` to benefit from the provided functionality of `AbstractClass` while also customizing or extending its behaviour as needed for the specific component's functionality.

Answer (score 0):

Inheritance: Use to inherit the properties/methods of the class (`AbstractClass`). Since the class is abstract, it just defines the common structure definitions, that must be present in the children that inherit it.

When you do inheritance, there is no need for adding in the providers array, seems like an unnecessary step IMHO.

Abstract class cannot be used as a component, **it's just used when you need to define a hierarchy of classes that share common attributes and behaviors**.

Answer (score 0):

The main reason is because of *Inheritance* or *Polymorphism*, however, this is not always clear, specially in the world of frontend development.

Furthermore, angular makes it more tricky by having the `forwardRef` function take seems to generate some confusion.

To provide a more comprehensive response, you need to consider that:

> Angular distinguishes components from services to increase modularity and reusability.

Why do I emphasize this (from the [Angular Doc](https://angular.io/guide/architecture-services))? Well because this is the key reason for the use of *Inheritance* or *Polymorphism*. Unlike what you are trying to do, *Inheritance* or *Polymorphism* tend to make more sense when used in Services, not Components.

Does that mean they can't be used in Components? Of course not, there are good use cases for it, but if you follow the idea that components should only care about the presentation and logic should be delegate to Services, you will tend to apply *Inheritance* or *Polymorphism* in Services, not Components.

Let's give a proper example regarding a good use case for `Inheritance`, and the use of `abstract` classes.

Consider that our app needs to provide the result for the calculation of some geometrical shapes, rectangles and triangles:

```
@Injectable()
abstract class ShapeService<T = any> {
    protected abstract calcArea(mesures: T): number;

    logArea(measures: T): void {
        console.log("The area of our shape is: ", this.calcArea(measures));
    }
}

interface Rectangle {
    width: number;
    height: number;
}

@Injectable()
class RectangleService extends ShapeService<Rectangle> {
    protected calcArea(measures: Rectangle): number {
        return measures.height * measures.width;
    }
}

interface Triangle {
    width: number;
    height: number;
}

@Injectable()
class TriangleService extends ShapeService<Triangle> {
    protected calcArea(measures: Triangle): number {
        return measures.height * measures.width / 2;
    }
}
```

In this case, both classes extend the `ShapeService` and therefor implement the `calcArea` method. Since we always want to log our area with the same message, we can abstract part of the logic into a method that our different services will implement `calcArea`, while the common portion is implemented in our abstract class to avoid duplication.

This is probably the most textbook example of why you tend to implement abstract classes. This particular common when you implement the [strategy design pattern](https://refactoring.guru/design-patterns/strategy/typescript/example) since a part of the strategy is may be common to all classes.

In this case, if you wanted to provide these classes to a component, you would do:

```
@Component([
    ...,
    standalone: true,
    providers: [
        { provide: ShapeService, useClass: RectangleService }
    ]
])
export class RectangleComponent {
    constructor(private readonly shapeService: ShapeService<Rectangle>) {}
}
```

But what if the service you wanted depends on something like the route that you are currently on? Well, this would also be a good solution to your problem. You would rely on the `useFactory` provider to ensure that you have the proper service without needing to inject both in your component:

```
@Component([
    ...,
    standalone: true,
    providers: [
        { 
            provide: ShapeService,
            useFactory: (route: ActivatedRouteSnapshot) => {
                if (route.paramMap.has('rectangle')) {
                    return new RectangleService();
                } else if (route.paramMap.has('triangle')) {
                    return new TriangleService();
                }
                throw new Error('An error')
            }
        }
    ]
])
export class ShapeComponent {
    constructor(private readonly shapeService: ShapeService) {}
}
```

Now, we can use the same component to calculate and log the shape we need depending on our route. The same component can be used to interact with the UI and the different services can be used to manage the calculation logic without our component understanding which is being used.

---

To answer your question:

> What is the purpose of both prividing and extending a class in
> Angular?

It is to break our code into more modular pieces where some common logic is shared and to ensure we use the class that we want in the appropriate place.